# Css not rendering properly after the script call

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, accordion

I am currently using two accordion bars where both have two different colours rendering when they are clicked.First one shows a green color.Functionality is to toggle the information needed down the bar when clicked on it.

Clicking again it should toggle back all the information rendering a different colour,for which i am using a java script for the toggle to happen. Previously we used to used three different images for this bar wheres as now,I need to remove the images.

As you can see in my .xhtml file a section-middle will be used as a primary bar and all the color attributes and moz-tool kit to make it rounded are declared in my CSS file.I am using moz-tool kit and jquery rounded corners to make my accordion corners rounded both in IE and mozilla.Its working charmingly in mozilla but in IE its not rendering the color for the bar when i click on it,the toggling operation is working properly as i can see the information in the bar popping up and down when i click on it.

My only problem is with the color of the bar as it is not rendering properly when its clicked on it.It stays the same green color even after the click.When i remove moz-took kit its working fine but with out rounded corners.I am unable to figure out the problem whether it is with java script or CSS.This is my java script and css and my xhtml file.is there any solution for this.Do i need to make any code change in my script?The rest of the site i am able to populate this bar perfectly.but seems like problem is coming when i use a script.

---

```
css for first green bar
#layout-container .section-open .section-middle {background-color:#99CC33;}
#layout-container #layout-detail .columns .section-middle { width: 624px; }
#layout-container #layout-detail .columns .section-open .section-left, #layout-container #layout-detail .columns .section-open .section-right, #layout-container #layout-detail .columns .section-closed .section-left, #layout-container #layout-detail .columns .section-closed .section-right {
    float: left;
    height: 20px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 6px;
-webkit-border-radius: 7px;-moz-border-radius: 7px
}
```

css for second bar

```
#layout-container #layout-detail .section-closed .section-middle{background-color:#efe8dc; background-image: url(../../images/icons5.png); background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position: 612px -1392px;-webkit-border-radius: 7px;-moz-border-radius: 7px;}
```

my xhtml

```
<ui:fragment rendered="#{current.index le 8 or current.last}">
            <div class="columns">
                <div
                    class="#{current.first ?'faq-accordion section-open' : 'faq-accordion section-closed'}">

                    <span class="section-middle">
                        <h2>
                            <h:outputText value="#{priority.statementDescription}" />
                        </h2> </span>
```

my script

```
$('.faq-accordion').live("click", function() {
        $(this).next('.content-toggle').toggle();
        // $('.show-all').show();
        // $('.hide-all').hide();

        if ($(this).hasClass('section-closed')){
            $(this).addClass('section-open');
            $(this).removeClass('section-closed');
        }
        else
        {
            $(this).addClass('section-closed');
            $(this).removeClass('section-open');
        }

        var total = $('.faq-accordion').length;
        var open = 0;

        for (i=0; i<total; i++) {
            if($('.faq-accordion').eq(i).hasClass('section-open')){
                open = open + 1;
            }
        }

        if (total != open) {
            $('.show-all').show();
            $('.hide-all').hide();

        }
        else {
            $('.hide-all').show();
            $('.show-all').hide();            
        }
    })


    $('.show-all').click(function(){
        $('.content-toggle').show();
        $('.content-toggle').prev('div').addClass('section-open');
        $('.content-toggle').prev('div').removeClass('section-closed');
        $(this).hide();
        $('.hide-all').show();
        return false;
    });       

    $('.hide-all').click(function(){
        $('.content-toggle').hide();
        $('.content-toggle').prev('div').addClass('section-closed');
        $('.content-toggle').prev('div').removeClass('section-open');
        $(this).hide();
        $('.show-all').show();
        return false;
    });
```

Comment: I tried to make your post more readable but gave up - it's really hard to tell what you're asking. Try breaking the text into paragraphs, correcting the spelling mistakes, and using far less words.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know.If this wolud help let me know,or i will make some more changes

Comment: Please please please add some formatting to your text. You're the one looking to have your question answered, so who do you make it so hard for people to help? I read a little bit and then just stopped.

Comment: I saw the wall of text and was tempted to click my back button. Break it into paragraphs and I'll actually read it.

Comment: guys,i am very sorry abt my question.so,bad of me when some one trying to help me out i am making them feel misarable. plzz do let me know once again if the question is still not understandable.i will try to give any more shots until it is easy to understand.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
-webkit-border-radius: 7px !important;-moz-border-radius: 7px !important;
```

I have used your code and !important fixed the issue.

Comment: Hai,there firstly thanks for the reply.i tried with !important but it coudnt fix my issue.My issue is mainly in IE did you check in IE or firefox.If you tried this in IE and worked.Please post that one in fiddle so that it wil be very helpfull.Thanks